t:Ab→Ab is a functor if one defines t(f)=f∣tG for every homomorphism f.
For an abelian group G let
$$tG=\{x\in G\:\mid x\text{ has a finite order }\}$$
denote its torsion subgroup. Prove that $t$ defines a functor $Ab\to Ab$ if one defines $t(f)=f_{∣tG}$ for every homomorphism $f.$
I know that I have to show that for $f,g\in Hom(A,B)$ where A,B∈objAb
t(f∘g)=(f∘g)∣tG=f∣tG∘g∣tG=t(f)∘t(g)
but I do not have idea how to prove it.

Please use MathJax instead of Unicode whenever you type a formula on this site. It’s pretty easy. You just enclose your formulae into the $ signs, for the most part.

When $f,g\in Hom(A,B),$ $f\circ g$ does not mean anything, unless $A=B.$ You want $g\in Hom(A,B),$ $f\in Hom(B,C).$

First we check that if $f \in \mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$, then $t(f) \in \mathrm{Hom}(tA, tB)$.
Let $f \in \mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$. The restriction of an abelian group homomorphism to a subgroup is an abelian group homomorphism. Therefore $f|_{tA} \in \mathrm{Hom}(tA, B)$. So we want to show that $f(tA) \subseteq tB$.
Let $x \in tA$. By definition $nx = 0$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $0 = f(nx) = nf(x)$. So $f(x) \in tB$. We can conclude that $f|_{tA} \in \mathrm{Hom}(tA, tB)$.
Now that this is established, we will prove that $t$ respects the identity morphisms and composition. Both results will follow almost immediately from the fact that $t(f)$ is defined by restriction.
Let $1_A \in \mathrm{Hom}(A,A)$ be the identity morphism for some $A \in \mathrm{Obj}(Ab)$. Then $1_A|_{tA} = 1_{tA} \in \mathrm{Hom}(tA, tA)$ since the restriction of the identity morphism to a subgroup of $A$ is the identity morphism on that subgroup.
Let $f \in \mathrm{Hom}(B,C)$ and $g \in \mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$. You have correctly stated that we want to show $t(f \circ g) = t(f) \circ t(g)$. By definition we want to show that $f|_{tB} \circ g|_{tA} = (f \circ g)|_{tA}$. Since we are working in the category of abelian groups, we can check that the morphisms are the same by checking that any two elements of $tA$ are sent to the same output. Let $x \in tA$, then $(f\circ g)|_{tA}(x) = (f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$ and $(f|_{tB} \circ g|_{tA})(x) = f|_{tB}(g(x)) = f(g(x))$.

Thanks. You have helped me a lot
